# Multiple images in target div from different source div

Tags: javascript, html

How to add single flower image from each `vase(source div)` to collection`(target div (id="p1"))`,So that the target div has three images from each `source div`.

I could manage to get only one image inside the `target div id="p1"`. I need three different images from each source div to be displayed  in `target div`.

### Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .main {
        height: 400px;
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    .p1 {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        border-style: outset;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .images {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .divs{
        float:left;
        padding:20px;
        margin:5px;
        border:solid #000 thin;
        }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="p1" class="p1"><img src="" alt="" /><p align="center"><b>COLLECTION</b></p></div>
        <div id="p2" class="divs">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-293063.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-611834.jpg" /></br><b>vase1</b>
        </div>
        <div id="p3" class="divs">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-771362.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-435833.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-661694.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-413011.jpg" /></br><b>vase2</b>
        </div>
        <div id="p4" class="divs">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-392478.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-558351.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-630909.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-302761.jpg" /></br><b>vase3</b>
        </div>
        <script>

            function myvase1(id) {               
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   

            }
             function myvase2(id) {               
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   

            }
            function myvase3(id) {               
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   

            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean it might be 9 total images in collection or 3 - one flower from each vase?

Comment: @neli yes, I mean 3-one flower from each vase

Comment: I have given you a solution with some JSFiddle examples of it working.  The images going into the target div need to be resized to fit neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following: If I posted what you didn't expected, comment on it. I will update the code.

```
 <div id="p1" class="p1">
     <div id="t1"></div>
     <input type="hidden" id="p1Hidden" />
     <input type="hidden" id="p2Hidden" />
     <input type="hidden" id="p3Hidden" />
     <p align="center">
         <b>COLLECTION</b>
     </p>
 </div>


  <script>
        function setImageSrc(src,vaseNum)
        {
           if(vaseNum == 1)
               document.getElementById("p1Hidden").value = src;
           else if(vaseNum == 2)
               document.getElementById("p2Hidden").value = src;
           else if(vaseNum == 3)
               document.getElementById("p3Hidden").value = src;
           if(document.getElementById("p1Hidden").value != "" && document.getElementById("p2Hidden").value != "" && document.getElementById("p3Hidden").value != "")
           {
               document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + document.getElementById("p1Hidden").value + "'/><img src='" + document.getElementById("p2Hidden").value + "'/><img src='" + document.getElementById("p3Hidden").value + "'/>";
           }
        }
        function myvase1(id) {               
                setImageSrc(id.getAttribute("src"),1);  

        }
         function myvase2(id) {               
                setImageSrc(id.getAttribute("src"),2); 

        }
        function myvase3(id) {               
               setImageSrc(id.getAttribute("src"),3);  

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything else there is something to fix.  When you use id="" on a page it should be unique.  Right now you have the same ids referring to 3 different objects.

Change your ids to something like

```
id="p2obj0"
id="p2obj1"
id="p2obj2"
id="p2obj3"

id="p3obj0"
id="p3obj1"
id="p3obj2"
id="p3obj3"

id="p4obj0"
id="p4obj1"
id="p4obj2"
id="p4obj3"
```

Each of your functions myvase1(), myvase2(), myvase3() is overwriting the full innerHTML.

change your code a tiny bit to

```
function myvase1(id) {               
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
}
function myvase2(id) {               
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
}
function myvase3(id) {               
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
}
```

I have changes your = to +=

This will just keep adding to your target div, there is no limit set and you have no way to restart.  So easy bit first, add a function to empty your div 'target'

```
function emptytarget() {               
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<p align=\"center\"><b>COLLECTION</b>";   
}
```

attach an event

```
<div id="p5" class="p5" onclick="emptytarget()"><p align="center"><b>RESET</b></p></div>
```

You will need to set some CSS to position this.

Now if you want to add only three flowers from each vase we are going to need to count.  You can either;

1. check your target div and count the flowers that are already in it from each vase.  If there are 3 from one then don't allow any more.  This is a bit tricky but doable.
2. the easy way to do it is to keep a running count with global variables, I think there is nothing wrong with using globals, if you do it properly.

So **outside your functions** set three counters.  These will be available to all your functions.

```
var vase1 = 0; //Global variable
var vase2 = 0; //Global variable
var vase3 = 0; //Global variable
```

now we modify the previous function to have the following;

```
//  Reset target content and counters
function emptytarget() {               
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "";   
  vase1 = 0;
  vase2 = 0;
  vase3 = 0;
}

function myvase1(id) {               
  if(vase1 < 3) document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
  vase1++;
}
function myvase2(id) {               
  if(vase2 < 3) document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
  vase2++;
}
function myvase3(id) {               
  if(vase3 < 3) document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
  vase3++;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/4650/embedded/result/) is the working page

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/4650/) is the code

I have written it this way so it is easy to follow, however you can do this in a more elegant way.  I am sure other contributors can improve my code but here is a start.

Change the globals to this

```
var vase = new Array();
vase['p2'] = 0;
vase['p3'] = 0;
vase['p4'] = 0; // Global variable declaration
```

Change your events from

```
onclick="myvase1(this)",.....
```

to

```
onclick="myvase('p2', this)"
onclick="myvase('p3', this)"
onclick="myvase('p4', this)"
```

replace the three functions with one

```
function myvase(source, id) {               
  if(vase[source] < 3) document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
  vase[source]++;
}
```

replace the reset with

```
function emptytarget() {               
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<p align=\"center\"><b>COLLECTION</b>";   
  for (key in vase) {
    vase[key] = 0;
  }
}
```

once more;

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w94r89mf/13/embedded/result/) is the working page

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w94r89mf/13/) is the code

Comment: I tried to show you how to do it to help you learn. The solution is there to help also. The images going into the target div need to be resized to fit neatly.